# myView.bounds.size return's same value for all screen sizes

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a subView called contentView which almost flush with the superView.

I designed the subView in Storyboard with iPhoneX and added the necessary constraints to stretch for all screen sizes.

On the different screen sizes the view appears to be stretched as defined by the the constraints but the bound.size of the view remains same on all screen size

```
contentView.bounds.width
```

the above on all screen sizes prints the following value

```
375.0
```

I am adding more subViews to my contentView according to it's width, but on all screen sizes I get the same value.

It seems that 375 is the width in points for iPhoneX on which I originally added the contentView.

Is there any reason for this as Googling for this problem didn't help.
I would really appreciate if any one points me in the right direction.

[Here are my constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZJd2.png)

Comment: show how you set the constraints

Comment: try running for iphone 5/5s.It will be 320.

Comment: @RatulSharker I have tried it returns the same value even on an iPad it returns the iPhone X width value

Comment: @Sh_Khan I have updated the post with my constraints

Comment: @NikhilMuskur where you print it, I mean in which function.

Comment: @AmitBattan in viewDidLoad

Comment: Try to print it in viewDidAppear

Comment: Add self.view.layoutIfNeeded() and print after it

Comment: @agibson007 great this solves my problem.. can you please explain or point me to any documentation on why I would need to call this before I access the size property of my subViews ?

Comment: @AmitBattan I need the values in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect constraints to be applied in `viewDidLoad()`, well it's too early. Views are only assumed to be constraint-ready in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

Comment: Thanks this solves my issue... Seems like I have to read up on View Life Cycle

Comment: @NikhilMuskur override func viewDidAppear,  this only gets called 1 time. viewDidLayoutSubviews can get called a lot of times...

Comment: @J.Doe Thanks now I don't have to protect my function against multiple calls of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: @J.Doe Unfortunately how can I then detect for orientation change, as I want to support landscape as well..

Answer (score 0):

**Add**

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
print(“\(myCustomView.bounds)”)
```

Then you can print the correct bounds.

This forces the view to update all sub views to the the constrained sizes before you check it. In viewDidLoad that is still going on so this makes sure that has happened.

You can do this in viewDidLayoutSubviews() as well but if the view is a subview of a subview it may not be correct even in that function.

Comment: Thanks for you reply... this solved my issue partially the height still was not set correctly only width was proper... using @keeshux solution resolved my issue fully

Comment: the safe area insets were not subtracted from it

Comment: just tested and not seeing that but no worries